# Android maps activity null object reference but I dont understand why

Tags: android, google-maps

So I'm trying to make a maps activity that displays the longitude and latitude of my current position in a toast, however I'm getting a `Null object reference` even though the object is instantiated one line before I reference it. `currentLocation` is declared above on create.

Error message points to second/third last line of code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.location.Location.mProvider' on a null object reference
```

Relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    currentLocation = new Location(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient));
    Toast.makeText(this, currentLocation.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation: "If a location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will be returned"

Answer (score 0):

getLastLocation inside onMapReady will check your last location which can be null when you are using it first time so you have to write this inside onConnected

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }



    mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();

    System.out.println("mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);


    System.out.println("mLastLocation " + mLastLocation);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {


    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);



}
```

Comment: I implemented this code in my onCreate method however the error has not changed

Comment: No you have to implement  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks on your activity then method onConnected gets override inside it you have to use this code.

Comment: @killiantos did you get the solution ?